# Sengrid mail not sending with wamp server php

Tags: php, api, email, wampserver

I'm using sengrid api to send mails and i installed curl and WAMP server. mail sttus code is 0 and body and header is empty. how to solve this issue.?

i tried php version 7.1 and 7.2 but it doesn't work

```
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
$email->setFrom("donayasara94@gmail.com", $subject);
$email->setSubject($subject);
$email->addTo($receiver, $subject);
$email->addContent("text/plain", $body);
$email->addContent(
     "text/html", $body
);
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid('api key');
    try {
       $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
       $returnArr = [
                'code' => $response->statusCode(),
                'body' => $response->body()
       ];
           echo json_encode($returnArr);                                        
           print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
           print_r($response->headers());
           print $response->body() . "\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      //echo 'Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    } /*end sending email*/
}
```

Comment: i'm using sengrid

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

1. Download cacert.pem file from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)
2. Save it to some location say c:\cacert\cacert.pem
3. Edit C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache(ver)\bin\php.ini change the line
   ';curl.cainfo' to curl.cainfo=c:\cacert\cacert.pem
4. Restart all services in wamp

Source: https://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/